# Remove leading whitespaces from a HTML file in Python

Tags: python

I need to do some replaces in a HTML file at the "text" level, that is, I cannot use a HTML parser because I'm not working with tags.

For example, I need to replace `var hls = new Hls(config);` with

```
            var config = {
                xhrSetup: function(xhr, url){
                    xhr.withCredentials = true;
                }
            }
            var hls = new Hls(config);
```

I'm finding that the `replace` function, when matching multiline strings like `</script>\n</body>` takes into consideration the whitespaces, so for example to add something before the `</script>`

```
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to `replace('</script>\n  </body>', 'alert(1);\n</script>\n</body>')`.

As I'll be working with different files, some may be indented using 2 chars, others 4... I'm interested in removing all the leading whitespaces, so that the previous snippets become:

```
var config = {
xhrSetup: function(xhr, url){
xhr.withCredentials = true;
}
}
var hls = new Hls(config);
```

or

```
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So that then, independently of the file, I could `replace('</script>\n</body>', 'alert(1);\n</script>\n</body>')`

I tried to use `lstrip()` but it seems to no be doing anything. That is:

```
with open('web.html') as web_page:
    web = web_page.read()
    print(web.lstrip())
```

will not remove the leading white spaces. `replace(' ', '')` isn't an option, as it breaks the code (e.g. `varconfig={`).

**TL;DR;**
How can I read a web file and remove all the leading white spaces in Python?

Comment: What does "I'm not working with tags" mean? You clearly are working with tags, and your life would be much simpler if you did use a parser. Can you explain why you don't think you can use one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not "clearly" working with tags, in fact, the first example is just javascript code.

Comment: But you are adding/removing/replacing text in relation to certain tags, like the `<script>` tag, aren't you?

Comment: Use a html parser, extract the desired `<script>` tags, update their contents, and rebuild the html.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you are focusing the issue to be related with HTML, and that's not the case. Forget about HTML. Imagine you have just a text file with `bbbb\ncccc`. Now you want to add `aaaa\n` before `bbbb` only when the next line is `cccc`. This is the actual problem, the HTML is just an example of the particular case I was working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you `read` the entire HTML file and `lstrip` the whole thing, i.e. you are only stripping the very first line (which probably does not have any indent anyway).

Instead, you have to read the lines individually or split the lines after reading, and then apply `lstrip` to each line.

```
for line in web_page: # read file one line at a time
    print(line.lstrip())

# read file en block, but split lines afterwards
print("\n".join(map(str.lstrip, web.splitlines())))
```

Or use regular expression `^\s+` for "whitespaces at beginning of line":

```
import re
print(re.sub(r"^\s+", "", web, flags=re.M))
```

But alternatively to removing the leading whitespaces, you can also use regular expressions for the actual replacement, using `\s*` for any number of spaces, and `\1` to re-insert the exact text that was matched, including the original whitespace.

```
print(re.sub(r"(</script>\s*</body>)", r"alert(1);\1", web, flags=re.M))
```